# Disabling AIX /usr/bin/sh clearing of LIBPATH, NLSPATH, and LD_LIBRARY_PATH

Tags: aix

I expect a shell not to modify `LIBPATH` and most other environment variables.
On some but not all AIX systems, `/usr/bin/sh` (notable for being the shell
behind system(3)) clears variables LIBPATH, LD_LIBRARY_PATH, and NLSPATH.
`ksh` and `bash` do not.  Test shell script:

```bash
export LIBPATH=/none1 LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/none2 NLSPATH=/none3 LiBPATH=/none4
for shell in /usr/bin/sh ksh bash; do
    echo "=== $shell"
    $shell -c env | grep /none
done
```

I expect output like this, and I get it on some AIX systems:

```
=== /usr/bin/sh
LiBPATH=/none4
NLSPATH=/none3
LIBPATH=/none1
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/none2
=== ksh
LiBPATH=/none4
NLSPATH=/none3
LIBPATH=/none1
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/none2
=== bash
LiBPATH=/none4
NLSPATH=/none3
LIBPATH=/none1
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/none2
```

Variable-clearing systems give this output instead:

```
=== /usr/bin/sh
LiBPATH=/none4
=== ksh
LiBPATH=/none4
NLSPATH=/none3
LIBPATH=/none1
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/none2
=== bash
LiBPATH=/none4
NLSPATH=/none3
LIBPATH=/none1
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/none2
```

How can one disable this variable-clearing behavior?  I'd like to disable it to restore compatibility of system(3) with older AIX and with Linux.

Differences observed between systems:

1. As of 2023-05-11, a system with $(oslevel -s)=7200-04-03-2038 did not clear these variables.
2. After some kind of system change and reboot on 2023-05-12, that same system now *does* clear these variables.  The system still reports level 7200-04-03-2038.  This system is gcc119.fsffrance.org, a member of the [GCC Compile Farm](https://cfarm.tetaneutral.net).  I don't have details on the system change.  (I inferred it from the uptime and from `find /usr /opt /etc -mtime -30 -ls 2>/dev/null`.)  I could ask the admin.
3. A system with oslevel 7100-05-06-2028 does not clear these variables.  This system is gcc111.fsffrance.org, also a member of the [GCC Compile Farm](https://cfarm.tetaneutral.net).

Shell versions for system (2), the variable-clearing system:

```
$ lslpp -l bos.rte.shell
  Fileset                      Level  State      Description         
  ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
Path: /usr/lib/objrepos
  bos.rte.shell              7.2.4.2  COMMITTED  Shells (bsh, ksh, csh)

Path: /etc/objrepos
  bos.rte.shell              7.2.4.2  COMMITTED  Shells (bsh, ksh, csh)
$ ls -l /usr/bin/ksh /usr/bin/sh
-r-xr-xr-x    5 bin      bin          317840 Sep 23 2020  /usr/bin/ksh
-r-xr-xr-x    5 bin      bin          317840 Sep 23 2020  /usr/bin/sh
```

On system (2), no package known to `lslpp` is newer than year 2020:

```
$ lslpp -Lc all | grep ':[0-9]\{4\}$' | sed 's/.*://' | sort | uniq -c
   1 1241
 297 1543
   2 1614
   8 1642
   6 1731
   4 1806
  42 1837
  46 1845
   2 1913
 332 1937
  43 2015
   1 2027
 117 2037
```

Comment: `system(3)` calls `/bin/sh` which is usually some version of Korn-shell. At startup, the shell might execute some rc-files (e.g. ~/.profile, /etc/profile, consult the manual and/or use `truss -f` to find out), one of these files might be responsible for unsetting your variables.

Comment: Good point.  Having changed the exec branch of the test script to
`execl("/bin/sh", "sh", "-c", "env", (char *)0);`, the variable clearing
happened in that branch, too.  I've simplified the question to be about the
shell, since the C-level differences were just obscuring things.

Per `truss -f`, none of the shells are reading any files.  (Adding
`BASH_ENV=/none_bash_env` to the environment causes truss to see bash opening
the file in question.)

Comment: Examine your `/usr/bin/sh` file: if it is either set-uid or set-gid, that explains the results, but it also means your system has been compromised.

Comment: It's not set-uid or set-gid; see the `ls -l` output in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`/etc/security/privcmds` contained:

```
/bin/sh:
        accessauths = ALLOW_ALL
```

Removing that and running `setkst` disabled the variable clearing.  Under the
removed configuration, role based access control (RBAC) ["governs the
privileges assigned to the
process"](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/aix/7.2?topic=files-etcsecurityprivcmds-file).
"For a process configured with RBAC elevated privileges" the question's three
variables and also `LDR_PRELOAD` [are
reset](https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/ibm-java-aix-reference-rbac-privileged-process-and-environment-variables).
Apparently, enrolling a process in RBAC is enough to reset the variables, even
if no RBAC privilege grants appear.

Answer (score 0):

I think there are a few misconceptions at work here and since the system(s) in question are not specified (see below for an explanation) it is not possible to directly answer the question now.

First off: the AIX levels I have at my command are (as per oslevel output):

> 6100-08-03-1339 (!)
> 7100-05-09-2148 
> 7200-05-06-2320 
> 7200-05-03-2148 
> 7200-05-05-2246 
> 7200-05-06-2320

Not one of them shows the problem described by you.

Furthermore, "sh" (which is */usr/bin/sh* in all AIX systems not older than 20 years) and "ksh" (which is /usr/bin/ksh) are the same. For instance, from the last mentioned system:

```
$ ls -l /usr/bin/ksh /usr/bin/sh
-r-xr-xr-x    5 bin      bin          326344 Jan 09 20:48 /usr/bin/ksh
-r-xr-xr-x    5 bin      bin          326344 Jan 09 20:48 /usr/bin/sh

$ diff -b /usr/bin/ksh /usr/bin/sh
```

Since (IIRC) AIX 4.1 the standard shell (=> sh) was the ksh88 and this is the case today. So if you don't have any really ancient (pre-2000) AIX system (there /usr/bin/sh was a Bourne shell), /usr/bin/sh is a Korn Shell 88 with the version information  "M-11/16/88f" (`set -o vi`, then press <kbd>Esc</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd>).

Also, the ksh *is* the default shell in AIX. According to the man page (`man sh`) of a 7.2.5.5-system:

> Refer to the syntax of the ksh command. The /usr/bin/sh file is linked to the Korn shell.

**1) The oslevel command**
The oslevel command will show the version, maintenance level (ML) and service pack (SP) information of the *lowest* complete ML/SP. That means, if all but one packages are at i.e. 10 and one package is at 9, it will display 9. The information is to be read as:

> $(oslevel -s)=7200-04-03-2038

The version is 7.2 (7200), ML 4 (04), SP 3 (03) and 2038 means this is the version issued in the 38th week of 2020 (there might be several dates the same ML/SP is issued, i.e. 7200-05-03-2136 and 7200-05-03-2148).

If you want to get version information specifically about your shells issue:

> `lslpp -l bos.rte.shell`

and post that here.

To get the version information for the rest of the system, don't use the command you used. Do it like this:

First, get a list of MLs/SPs the system is aware of (along with a possible output):

```
# instfix -i | grep -e AIX_ML -e _SP
All filesets for 7.2.0.0_AIX_ML were found.
All filesets for 7200-00_AIX_ML were found.
All filesets for 72-00-011543_SP were found.
All filesets for 72-00-021614_SP were found.
All filesets for 72-05-032148_SP were found.
[...]
Not all filesets for 72-04-062220_SP were found.
Not all filesets for 72-05-042219_SP were found.
```

Next, select one of these keywords and find out which packages are downlevel relative to that ML/SP with another invocation of the `instfix` command:

```
# instfix -qick [keyword]
```

For instance, (from the machine above):

```
# instfix -qick 72-04-062220_SP | grep ':-:'
72-04-062220_SP:bos.rte.streams:7.2.4.1:7.2.4.0:-:AIX 7200-04-06-2220 Service Pack
72-04-062220_SP:openssh.msg.EN_US:8.1.102.2105:8.1.102.2104:-:AIX 7200-04-06-2220 Service Pack
72-04-062220_SP:openssh.msg.en_US:8.1.102.2105:8.1.102.2104:-:AIX 7200-04-06-2220 Service Pack
```

I would need to update *bos.rte.streams*, *openssh.msg.EN_US* and *openssh.msg.en_US* to get to this servicepack. Grepping for ":+:" instead of ":-" you can find packages which are higher than the SP/ML given in the keyword.

Anyway, I suppose the version is not your real problem, because even my ancient AIX 6.1 image (or, rather: the shells in them) handles the environment correctly.

There are a few pointer where you could look:

**1 - `/etc/environment`**
This is a system-wide configuration file for *every* process.

**2 - `/etc/profile`**
System-wide shell profile, overridden by ~/.profile

**3 - `~/.profile`**
user-specific session startup-script

**4 - `~/.kshrc`**
(default) user-specific shell startup script. Can be named differently, depending on the environment variable `$ENV`, set in `~/.profile`. Look there for something like:

```
export ENV=/path/to/some/file
```

Comment: I've added more version information to the question.  Multiple shell
implementations react to the name under which they're called, so the called name
matters even if binaries match.

The question's test code had ceased to use execl().  (That comment discussion
involved an earlier iteration of this question.)  For what it's worth, execle()
is the variant that changes the environment; execl() does not.  One can locate that
information by searching for `EnvironmentPointer` in `man execl`.

Comment: The `ENV` environment variable is not set.  The test behaves the same way under an empty environment (`env -i`).